# Fast.Ai EarlyStoppingCallback does not work

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, fast-ai

[image]

```
callbacks = [EarlyStoppingCallback(learn, monitor='error_rate', min_delta=1e-5, patience=5)]
learn.fit_one_cycle(30, callbacks=callbacks, max_lr=slice(1e-5,1e-3))
```

As you can see, I use patience = 5 and min_delta=1e-5 and monitor='error_rate'

> My understanding is: patience tells how many epochs it waits if improvement is less than min_delta on the monitored value, in this case it's error_rate.

So if my understanding was correct, then it would not stop at Epoch 6.

So is this my understanding wrong or the debug in fast.ai lib ?

Comment: A couple of writing tips are suggested: (1) text data is best presented as text - please delete the image and use formatting tools instead; (2) please-help-me requests are extraneous here, and should not be added. Technical writing is preferred.

Comment: hi @halfer thanks for letting know. I will keep it in mind. since the text data is lost already, I will do it next time. As to the point 2, I do not think I have "please-help-me" requests. If you do think there is, please let me know. thanks

Comment: No problem. I edited the post earlier, removing "Could someone help, please".

Comment: @halfer oh~~ thanks ~!

Answer (score 3):

It keeps track of the best error rate and compares the `min_delta` to the difference between this epoch and that value:

```
class EarlyStoppingCallback(TrackerCallback):
...
if self.operator(current - self.min_delta, self.best):
    self.best,self.wait = current,0
else:
    self.wait += 1
    if self.wait > self.patience:
        print(f'Epoch {epoch}: early stopping')
        return {"stop_training":True}
...
```

So `self.wait` only increases if the decrease in error was large enough. Once the 5th time occurs it stops.

```
np.greater(0.000638 - 1e-5, 0.000729)
```

```
False
```

There does seem to be an issue though, because clearly if the error rate jumped very high we would not want to assign this to `self.best`. And I believe the point of this callback is to stop training if the error rate starts to increase - which right now it is doing the opposite.

So in `TrackerCallback` there might need to be a change in:

```
mode_dict['auto'] = np.less if 'loss' in self.monitor else np.greater
```

to

```
mode_dict['auto'] = np.less if 'loss' in self.monitor or 'error' in self.monitor else np.greater
```

Comment: actually, the self.operator should be np.greater() as the mode='auto'

Comment: hi there, thanks for the update. I have submitted my PR for this one. Only minor difference:  ```np.less if 'loss' or 'error' in self.monitor ....``` . Also a workaround is: to set mode='min'

Comment: Also, the ```self.wait``` doesn't decrease, it gets reset to 0 from the code.

Comment: @Franva I think that's purposeful because you want early stopping when the error rate has `consistently` increased over a certain number of iterations